# Is there any way to change username field label in user authentication login page?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-login

[Right now login page looked like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUsOy.jpg)

I want to change label of username field to Team Name

Note: I'm using builtin LoginView

Comment: Perhaps the simplest way is to override the template `registration/login.html` and set the label what you want

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView) `LoginView` has an attribute called `authentication_form` (typically just a form class). Defaults to `AuthenticationForm`.

You can create a form class that inherits from `AuthenticationForm`, set the label of the username field and assign it to your `LoginView` over `authentication_form` attribute.

forms.py

```
from django import forms    
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm, UsernameField


class CustomAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = UsernameField(
        label='Team Name',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autofocus': True})
    )
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

from .forms import CustomAuthenticationForm


class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    authentication_form = CustomAuthenticationForm
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', CustomLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
]
```

Comment: Dont forget URL change - `path('login/', CustomLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),`

Answer (score 1):

Just change the label's text of your username field like this:

```
 class LoginForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        fields = ['username','password']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for fieldname in ['username']:
            self.fields[fieldname].label = 'Email'
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is override the Django admin authentication form.
In my case, I needed to override the username label since I wanted to allow users to use either their phone number or email to log in.

forms.py

```
 from django import forms
 from django.contrib.admin.forms import AdminAuthenticationForm
 from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm, UsernameField
 from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class CustomAdminAuthenticationForm(AdminAuthenticationForm):
    """
    A custom authentication form used in the admin app.
    """
    error_messages = {
        **AuthenticationForm.error_messages,
        'invalid_login': _(
            "Please enter the correct phone number or email and password for a staff "
            "account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive."
        ),
    }

    username = UsernameField(
        label='Email/Phone number',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autofocus': True})
    )
```

admin.py

```
import CustomAdminAuthenticationForm from {whatever_location}

from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.login_form = CustomAdminAuthenticationForm
```